# How to use Django mail_managers function to print utf8?

Tags: python, django

I want create contact app that can let user send feedback to terminal. I use `mail_managers` to do this thing. But I cannot solve code problem.

```
body = u"信息来自:%s\n\n\t%s" % (email,text)

mail_managers(full_reason, body)
```

I want terminal print below:

```
信息来自:youremail@domain.com

    成功
```

Actually terminal print below:

```
淇℃伅鏉ヨ嚜:youremail@domain.com

    鎴愬姛
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the top of your python file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: I have add this line before.